# Integrating REST Web API App with SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, websocket, signalr, asp.net-web-api2

Objective: facilitate chat between 2 users by storing a new message in the DB (posted to Web API) and push it out to a single listening client (SignalR).

Here are my concerns:

- I can't find any design patterns that address this other than [Command and Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS) Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn568103.aspx) and [Event Sourcing Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589792.aspx). Both of these seem focused on complex real-time applications. My application has a lot of traditional REST functionality, but for now the only real-time component is the chat so it doesn't seem necessary to use one of these patterns.
- Is there a simpler way to integrate a REST based website (Web API) with a real-time component (SignalR)?
- What I'm doing now feels like I'm mixing two entirely different things.

I've thought to try:

- Coupling my POST handler to my push handler using [events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ff921122.aspx) - though I'm not sure that helps me because I don't expect the "send message" portion of my app to evolve a part from the "receive" portion.
- Moving all my push logic into a job handled by a message broker - which again doesn't seem necessary, but would create better separation. My understanding according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193451/should-signalr-server-side-methods-be-async-when-calling-clients) is that SignalR uses an in-memory message broker such that the broadcast is not waiting for the messages to be received so an external message broker isn't necessary unless I really need to scale out.

Maybe my application is too simple to need a better design?

Here's what I have so far:

```
public class chatPush
{
    public chatPush(){}

    public push(string msg)
    {
        try{
            string jsonMsg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg);
            await Clients.User(userId).send(jsonMsg);
        }
        catch
        {
            string errorMsg = //error with msg
            await Clients.User(userId).send(errorMsg);
        }
    }
}

async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostMessage(Message msg)

    db.Messages.Add(msg);

    try
    {
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch
    {
        //return error in JSON
    }

    //if update succeeded push it out
    _chatPush.push(jsonMsg);

    return //Success or Error code
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need to use any complex design patterns while your needs are this simple. SignalR works nicely just in the POST/etc. handlers of API and MVC.

A more complex design would help you if you need to scale out to multiple front-end servers, since each user is only going to connect to one of your SignalR hosts, so you need to worry about persistent user-connection mappings via backplane or database. But SignalR has decent documentation for that once you need it.

**In terms of a basic design I have a few suggestions:**

1) If you have a MessageHub on the server side, create a MessageHubHelper to easily push data to the right user.

```
[Authorize]
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
}

public static class MessageHubHelper
{
    private static readonly IHubContext _hubContext =
        GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessageHub>();

    public static IHubContext Context
    {
        get { return _hubContext; }
    }

    public static void Send(User user, Message message)
    {
        _hubContext.Clients.User(GetUserId(user)).Send(message);
    }

    public static void DoSomethingElse(User user, Message message)
    {
        _hubContext.Clients.User(GetUserId(user)).DoSomethingElse(message);
    }

    private static string GetUserId(User user)
    {
        return user.IdentityUser.UserName;
    }
}
```

2) Make sure you only push data if your database commits succeed (e.g. after the SaveChangesAsync in the try {}, unless the catch will throw/return early).

3) You shouldn't need to manually deal with JSON. Just push objects down and the C# SignalR libraries will handle the encoding and decoding for you.

4) In my experience SignalR can be a bit flaky with its reconnects, especially with the IUserIdProvider (I've seen cases where client and server both think they're reconnected but no pushes actually go through). So, I recommend something like https://github.com/DamianEdwards/NDCLondon2013/tree/master/UserPresence to give you more solid (or at least more debuggable) user presence management.